# Inspect WebdriverIO spec variables

Tags: debugging, webdriver-io

I figured out, that I can use `browser.pause();` to stop the execution of the browser and inspect its current variables, but how do I inspect the variables of my WebdriverIO test source?

Of course I could call `console.log()` if I would like to know a value. But for every try I would have to restart the complete test suite, or I would need to comment every other test.

Instead, I would ideally like to stop the execution in one line and inspect all available variables.

Does somebody has a solution for that, or an other idea?

Comment: Hey @Sandro! Wanted to update my answer with *an advanced debugging approach using ChromeDev tools plugin for WebdriverIO*, which is probably the way to go right now.  

Can we change that accepted answer? The current one has NO VALUE for others coming to see your question. Cheers & Happy Holidays!

Comment: Hi @iamdanchiv, I like your `debug()` solution as it's quick and easy. But why do you think that remote debugging has "NO VALUE"?

Comment: Hey @Sandro! You're right, my wording wasn't spot on. By *NO VALUE*, I meat to say that it is a very specific answer, tailored to help people who are using *that specific IDE*. Switch the IDE (*for w/e reason*) & **BOOM!**, you need to configure the debugger once more. This can quickly be a pain to keep up with, not to mention the time investment. I propose a **universal approach**, by remote debugging your checks inside the browser, w/o the need for other plugins & misc software appendices. I'll try to update the answer the next days... Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the matter of webdriver-io, but the IDE you are using. What you are looking for is a `remote debugging` feature of an IDE. I've been doing that with Webstorm successfully.

Have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLMyI7QKcwg) on how to run setup test runner in Webstorm.

Answer (score 1):

For people coming here in hopes of an easier debug process of their **[WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io/)** test cases, take a look at the **[.debug()](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/debug.html)** command.

It doesn't do exactly what @Sandro was looking for, but it offers *an alternative* to changing your text-editor for a fancy, lumbering IDE:

- stops the execution of your current running test (just add `browser.debug()` after the line you want your "breakpoint");
- turns your terminal into a [read-eval-print-loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop);
- grants you access to the `browser` object in the state in which it is found, alongside all the other [API commands](http://webdriver.io/api.html).

Drawbacks:

- you will have to "recreate" some of the setup until that point (variables and contained values are not accessible from the REPL interface).

**!Note:** If you are using the [WDIO testrunner](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/gettingstarted.html), make sure you increase the `timeout` property of your test framework your are using (e.g. Mocha, Cucumber, or Jasmine) in order to prevent the continuation due to a test timeout.

```
mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 9999999
},
```