# Is there a way in nightwatch to get access to a button's onClick handler code?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have a link defined like so:

```
<a onclick={() => {console.log('Hello')}} />
```

I want to inspect the `onClick` function code in Nightwatch (maybe as a string), to check if the word `Hello` is in the code. Different links can have different texts within the `console.log`. The one above has `Hello` whereas another one can have `Hi`. So I want to be able to inspect that code to check which has a specific text.

I tried doing this, but the `result` variable doesn't contain the `onClick` handler code:

```
browser.element('xpath', 'SOME_XPATH', function(result) {
    console.log('RESULT OBJECT: ', result);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is! The `onclick` represents an attribute in the context of the anchor you specified (`<a>`). So you can use either [getAttribute](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/getAttribute.html), or [getAttributeById](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/elementIdAttribute.html).

Extending your code, it should look something like this:

```
return browser.element('xpath', 'yourXPathSelector', (result) => {
  browser.elementIdAttribute(result.value.ELEMENT, 'onclick', (res) => {
    console.log('RESULT OBJECT: ', res.value);
    // > do your Hi|Hello check here <
  });
});
```

I think the shortest, laziest way to do it would be to assert the acceptance criteria right away using Nightwatch's [Expect API](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#expect-api):

```
browser.expect.element('a').to.have.attribute('onclick')
.which.matches(/[Hi|Hello]/);
```

Comment: If I am using React and my anchor tag was like this (with the camelCase `onClick`): `<a onClick={...} />`, should I use camelCase `onClick` in the attribute method above? Like: `browser.expect.element('a').to.have.attribute('onClick')
.which.matches(/[Hi|Hello]/);` It doesn't seem to work and it says the anchor tag doesn't seem to have the `onClick` attribute.

Comment: @CapturedTree well, yes you should always use the exact attribute name (so `browser.elementIdAttribute(result.value.ELEMENT, 'onClick', (res) => { // bla bla });` as per your remark). Buuuuut, bear in mind React loads these asynchronously, best-effort. You should use a `waitUntil()`, or a `pause()` to make sure that `onClick` was actually present on the anchor in the moment the client sent the GET for that respective `ELEMENT's attribute`.

Comment: Hmm ok I tried using `onClick` and it keeps returning me in the `console.log('RESULT OBJECT: ', res.value);`. I will try to look into this a little more.

Comment: Hey again @CapturedTree! Well, that code should return something like `RESULT OBJECT:  {() => {console.log('Hello')}}`. I don't see how you're getting `console.log('RESULT OBJECT: ', res.value);`. Hmmm... best way to debug this is to add a `browser.debug()` inside your `browser.element` statement & debug step-by-step in the terminal. If you need help with this, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47815228/1458144) answer. Hope it help!

Comment: Cool sounds good. I will try it out and let you know what was wrong as well. Thanks a lot for the help :)